# Dataset Pivoting multiple related records to single one

Tags: python, pivot, pivot-table

I have numeric data within Student marks and I would like to have single record for every Student with all his related data spread into many records.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([('Adel', "Subj1", 3.50  ,2.57),
                   ('Adel', "Subj2", 2.75  ,3.6  ),

                   ('Alexa',"Subj1", 1.75  ,3.25) ,
                   ('Alexa',"Subj3", 3.15  ,2.25) ], 
                  columns=('Name', "Subj","Med", "Ach" ))
```

I developed a long loop statement and have the underneath table,  but I thought there is maybe a better way . 
[image]

Any shortcut for a such pivot table?
Of course, I may have missing Data since not all Students attend all Courses.

Comment: Did you check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: @Itamar I updated may question. The link above answers partially the question but still keep a single ID record splitted. 
I added the kind of records I expected to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```py
df2=df.pivot(index="Name", columns="Subj", values=["Med", "Ach"]).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
#flatten index - I assumed that's what you're going for:
df2.columns=["_".join(el) for el in df2.columns]
```

Output:

```py
       Subj1_Med  Subj2_Med  ...  Subj2_Ach  Subj3_Ach
Name                         ...
Adel        3.50       2.75  ...        3.6        NaN
Alexa       1.75        NaN  ...        NaN       2.25
```

Comment: THANKS, This is what I want, I guess my question was not fruitless , and don't know why I got that vote for it. 
Any how, Thanks,